Failed to use ILI9486 display with esp32-s3 (targetting to use rust)
My gloal is to connect slint with the waveshare screen on the esp32 ansusing rust.
i have spend literaly days searching to display something on the screen
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(C)
I've wire the screen following this (and according to the doc ) :
https://europe1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/7/2/1/721d0c0306133e962fcfbbcd239eff1798942e56.png
so to achieve my goal i tried as a first step to display something on the screen
but I've never been able to display anything
[edit 2]
there is my code :
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use esp_backtrace as _;
use esp_hal::{
    delay::Delay,
    gpio::{Io, Level, NoPin, Output},
    prelude::*,
    spi::{master::Spi, SpiMode}};

use embedded_graphics::{prelude::*, primitives::Rectangle, pixelcolor::Rgb565,primitives::PrimitiveStyleBuilder};
use display_interface_spi::SPIInterface;
use embedded_hal_bus::spi::ExclusiveDevice;
use mipidsi::{models::ILI9486Rgb565, Builder};

extern crate alloc;
use core::mem::MaybeUninit; //clone, 

fn init_heap() {
    const HEAP_SIZE: usize = 32 * 1024;
    static mut HEAP: MaybeUninit<[u8; HEAP_SIZE]> = MaybeUninit::uninit();

    unsafe {
        esp_alloc::HEAP.add_region(esp_alloc::HeapRegion::new(
            HEAP.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u8,
            HEAP_SIZE,
            esp_alloc::MemoryCapability::Internal.into(),
        ));
    }
}

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    

    let peripherals = esp_hal::init(esp_hal::Config::default());


    let mut delay = Delay::new();
    let io = Io::new(peripherals.GPIO, peripherals.IO_MUX);
    
    
    // slint use heap, setup allocator
    init_heap();

    esp_println::logger::init_logger_from_env();

    log::info!("dbg -- 1");

    // -------- Setup clocks --------
    let sclk = io.pins.gpio12;
    let miso = io.pins.gpio13;
    let mosi = io.pins.gpio11;
    let mut cs_screen = Output::new(io.pins.gpio10,Level::High);
    let _cs_touch = Output::new(io.pins.gpio9,Level::High);
    let mut rst = Output::new(io.pins.gpio18,Level::High);
    let mut dc = Output::new(io.pins.gpio17,Level::High);

    rst.set_low();
    delay.delay(10.millis());
    rst.set_high();

    let spi = Spi::new(
        peripherals.SPI2,
        500.kHz(),
        SpiMode::Mode0,
    )
    .with_pins(sclk, mosi, miso,NoPin);

    log::info!("dbg -- 2");

    let ed_spi = ExclusiveDevice::new(spi, &mut cs_screen, delay).unwrap();

        
    // Créer l'interface SPI sans contrôle de CS
    let di = SPIInterface::new(ed_spi, &mut dc);
    let mut display = Builder::new(ILI9486Rgb565, di)
        .reset_pin(rst)
        .display_size(320, 480)
        .init(&mut delay).unwrap();

    log::info!("dbg -- 3");

    display.clear(Rgb565::BLACK).unwrap();
    //Dessiner un rectangle rouge

    loop {
        let style = PrimitiveStyleBuilder::new()
        .fill_color(Rgb565::RED)
        .build();

        Rectangle::new(Point::new(50, 50), Size::new(50, 50))
            .into_styled(style)
            .draw(&mut display)
            .unwrap();

        log::info!("dbg -- 4");
        delay.delay(1000.millis());
    }
}

the spi signals looks ok but still nothing on the display
im not sure if the screen support 3.3v spi level


Waveshare sells a whole lot of different displays

The display could be using ILI9488 instead of ILI9486 for 480x320.

I couldn't find the information on their site, so I asked waveshare, and they confirmed that the screen uses an ILI9486 chip, but they could have made a mistake.
I will test with the ILI9488 driver

[ return from waveshare ]
This screen doesn't support 3.3V. If it's used under this voltage for a long time, the screen will be damaged.
It is recommended that you use the product recommended below to transplant to ESP32. For this product, we have provided Arduino examples.
https://www.waveshare.net/shop/3.5inch-TFT-Touch-Shield.htm
[]
So, i couldn't test it right away with a logic-level adapter.
And it's not impossible that I killed the screen.
anyway, i'll put the topic in resolute and update the post when i can.
